# How to allow users to download from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have looked on the docs and couldn't find the mention of a file downloading directly to the user from my firebase storage. I saw CORS but is that what I need to use?

I want a user to click on a download symbol on a picture and be able to get it.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "file downloading directly to the user"?  Are you trying to do something other than what's already documented?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson I actually didn't realize that the below docs mentioned was what I needed I have created a new question about a CORS error that has stumped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54338418/how-do-i-fix-cors-error-from-firebase-storage

Answer (score 0):

CORS is one way of handling http requests, intended to help you control cross-origin requests.  That is unrelated to getting a download link for a file in Firebase Storage.  What you want is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files